# Why is my TPL Dataflow Actionblock not executing in parallell?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, azure-functions, tpl-dataflow

I am trying to execute some web requests in parallell but for some reason it all runs sync one after the other and I cannot figure out why

The code is fairly simple as follows

```
 ConcurrentBag<string> documentsToImportInBatch = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

            var actionBlocHapiTest = new ActionBlock<Tuple<string, string>>(
                async request =>
            {
                var uriArticleTest = $"https://xxxx.com/omni-product"
                    + $"/api/v1/brands/0/articles/{request.Item1}?"
                    + $"channelIds=1&season={request.Item2}";
                var response = await staticHttpClient.GetAsync(uriArticleTest);
                var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                Article article = new Article
                {
                    Brand = brand,
                    UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now.ToString("s"),
                    Source = source,
                    ItemLevel = Enums.ItemLevel.Article,
                    DataType = Enums.DataType.DetailedItemInformation,
                    DetailedData = JObject.Parse(jsonString)
                };
                documentsToImportInBatch.Add(
                    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(article));

            }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
            });

            foreach (var itemTuple in articleAndSeasonList)
            {
                actionBlocHapiTest.Post(new Tuple<string, string>(
                    itemTuple.Item1, itemTuple.Item2));
            }
            actionBlocHapiTest.Complete();
            await actionBlocHapiTest.Completion;
```

I can see from performance monitoring that it only executing 1 request or so per second where I expected it to be a lot more.

Why is it not filling the block and emptying it in parallell with 10 parallell requests ?

Comment: Suggest do some logging/tracing before and after each httpclient call logging time and task info. It may just be that the called service is throttling.

Comment: I see only 200 OK requests no other throttling codes coming back

Comment: But are your calls initiated sequentially, or in parallel?

Comment: *I can see from performance monitoring that it only executing 1 request* how are you doing this?

Comment: I bet it's not an `ActionBlock` issue. You should get the same behavior if you created the `Task`s manually and awaited them with `Task.WhenAll`. Something else is serializing your requests.

Comment: @Liam azure application insights

Comment: @StuartLC how can I check that?

Comment: We're going to need more info. Your code looks fine to me, so there is something else at play. What that could be `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. So your deploying this in azure? As what?

Comment: @Liam deployed as a azure timer triggered function, I will post the entire function in a bit when i get home, its not a lot more code though

Comment: Have you read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/architecture/best-practices/background-jobs?

Comment: @Liam yes many times

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes you were right, I was starting the input to the block paging through one by one instead of sending the intended large list to the block for processing

Answer (score 0):

figured out the issue, before my action block I had a web request paging through creating the list that the action block used it would submit one by one to the action block stead of building the list and then submit all to the action block so in fact the block itself did process everything it had it’s just that it only got one entry at the time, once I fixed that and sent the full list to the block it worked as expected and processed in parallel as expected.

Comment: You still have a problem - that documentsToImportInBatch. If you want output, use TransformBlock which already has an output buffer. `ConcurrentBag<T>` is a specialized class, it's not meant to be used as a general purpose concurrent collection. You can link blocks together and eg download data using one block and parse the data in the next block, with different DOPs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know I can but does it provide any benefit? This use case is so simple, what would the benefits be of using more blocks and block types? And please don’t misunderstand this comment as arguing against what you said, I am genuinely trying to learn, and after studying block to block communications seems overkill for this use case but I am very new to this so happy to learn

Comment: If you have so many URLs to check that you needed an ActionBlock, yes. Besides, right now you had to *add extra code* to push the results to ConcurrentBag. Had you used a TransformBlock, all you had to do would be read the results once the block finished

Comment: Another option is to link to a BufferBlock and just read that when the transformblock completes. That's still less code than what you have right now

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos interesting I need read more documentation I think I didnt see that part where I could read directly from a block

Comment: [BufferBlock.TryReceiveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.bufferblock-1.tryreceiveall?view=netcore-3.0)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos any documentation pointer I am trying to google but maybe you have one handy specifically about reading from block

Comment: I just posted it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos neat so I would link my action block to this block and build a chain ? Is that what you mean?